# IndexOutOfBoundsException No Get(0) do Crawler jsoup

Tags: java, html, web-crawler, jsoup

Gostaria de conseguir os nomes das empresas que aparecem numa pesquisa do tipo "Farmacias em Santo Andre" no Google Maps.

```
Erro: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64) 
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70) 
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248) 
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372) 
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:458) 
at crawlergooglemap.CrawlerGoogleMap.main(CrawlerGoogleMap.java:48)
 C:\Users\Eugene\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
 C:\Users\Eugene\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 7 seconds)
```

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {

    String url;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Cole a URL do maps:"); 
    url = s.next(); 
    Document page = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); 
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){ 
        String empresa = page.getElementsByAttribute("section-result-title").get(0).selectFirst("h3").text(); 
        if(empresa.length() != 0){ 
            System.out.println(empresa); 
        }
       else{ 
           System.out.println("0"); 
       }
    } 
}
```

Parte do HTML do site:

```html
<div class="section-result-title-container">
  <h3 class="section-result-title">
    <span jstcache="134">Farmácia Nazaré</span>
    <button jstcache="135" style="display:none"></button>
  </h3>
  <span jstcache="136" class="section-ads-placecard" style="display:none">Anúncio</span>
  <span jstcache="137" class="section-hotel-ads-url" style="display:none">Anúncio</span>
```

Comment: Se deu esse erro é porque `getElementsByAttribute` não encontrou nada e retornou uma lista vazia. Neste caso, bastaria verificar antes se a lista é vazia (usando `isEmpty()`, por exemplo)

Comment: Blz, isso "resolveu", agora eu percebi que o programa não pega nenhuma informação, o isEmpty() sempre da 1

Comment: Se está vazio, então não existe nenhum elemento com o atributo `section-result-title`. Mas se quer obter os resultados, talvez seja melhor usar a [API do Google Maps](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java) em vez de acessar o HTML e tentar extrair dados do mesmo. Obs: não testei esse link, foi um que apareceu nos resultados de busca, mas vc pode procurar outros, caso queira. Acessar a API diretamente me parece mais simples que destrinchar o HTML (mesmo que a API possua limite de acessos e a partir de certa quantidade passe a cobrar)

Comment: No caso eu tava pegando uma classe com esse nome e usando get Attribute, mas ja mudei pra get class e não vai tb, e a classe ta la sim, olha ai uma parte do site, (e valeu pela API):

<div class="section-result-title-container"> <h3 class="section-result-title"> <span jstcache="134">Farmácia Nazaré</span> <button jstcache="135" style="display:none"></button> </h3> <span jstcache="136" class="section-ads-placecard" style="display:none">Anúncio</span> <span jstcache="137" class="section-hotel-ads-url" style="display:none">Anúncio</span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do Jsoup, o método [`getElementsByAttribute`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByAttribute-java.lang.String-) recebe o nome do atributo a ser buscado. No caso do seu HTML, você parece estar querendo buscar este elemento:

```html
<h3 class="section-result-title">
```

Repare que o **nome** do atributo é `class`, e o **valor** é `section-result-title`. O método `getElementsByAttribute` recebe o nome do atributo, mas você estava passando o valor, por isso ele não encontra nada (e a lista de elementos é vazia, por isso `get(0)` dá `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, pois você está tentando acessar um elemento que não existe).

O que você precisa nesse caso é do método [`getElementsByAttributeValue`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByAttributeValue-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```java
// procura os elementos que possuem class="section-result-title"
Elements results = page.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "section-result-title");
if (!results.isEmpty()) {
    String empresa = results.get(0).text();
    if (empresa.length() != 0) {
        System.out.println(empresa);
    } else {
        System.out.println("0");
    }
}
```

Repare também que eu verifico se a lista de elementos retornada é vazia, pois se for, o `get(0)` continuará dando erro. Se a lista não for vazia, eu prossigo com o restante do código.

---

Outra alternativa é usar o método [`select`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select-java.lang.String-):

```java
Elements results = page.select("h3[class=section-result-title]");
if (!results.isEmpty()) {
    ....
}
```

No caso, estou procurando os elementos `h3` que possuem o atributo `class` com o valor `section-result-title` (mais sobre esta sintaxe na [documentação](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)).

---

Outro detalhe é que não entendi porque você só está pegando o primeiro elemento da lista. Se quiser percorrer todos os elementos encontrados, basta fazer um `for` simples:

```java
Elements results = page.select("h3[class=section-result-title]");
for (Element el : results) {
    String empresa = el.text();
    if (empresa.length() != 0) {
        System.out.println(empresa);
    } else {
        System.out.println("0");
    }
}
```

Assim, se a lista for vazia, ele nem entra no `for`, e você não precisa ficar verificando se ela é vazia. Mas a intenção era pegar apenas o primeiro elemento, então use os códigos anteriores.

Comment: Tentei das maneiras que vc mostrou e o Results continua Empty, será que a Google tem alguma proteção contra crawler?

Comment: Faça `System.out.println(page)` e veja como está o HTML

Comment: É, o arquivo que salva é muito diferente do site, cheio de partes com null, creio que eles usem alguma proteção, até porque eles tem uma api que vendem. Valeu a ajuda